# SQL Union with group by and sum

Tags: sql

I have a database with 2 columns that are (and need to be) the same type of customer ID. I am trying to so an SQL query that will list how many times each Customer ID shows up in the table. So far I have what is below, I need each individual ID to add together so it is only listed once.
[image]

```
SELECT  TblMatch.CustomerID1, Count(TblMatch.[Match ID]) AS [TotalMatch ID]
FROM TblMatch
GROUP BY TblMatch.CustomerID1
UNION
SELECT TblMatch.CustomerID2, Count(TblMatch.[Match ID]) AS [TotalMatch ID]
FROM TblMatch
GROUP BY TblMatch.CustomerID2;
```

Comment: you wanted mysql sql and msaccess formats?

Comment: So which database is it? you need to pick one.

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL at all.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: I've removed all those tags. Add one of them back, the one for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Sorry about tagging the wrong thing, my teacher told us MySQL and MSAccess were the same

Comment: They are similar. The SQL database concept has been around since the 70's, and the language is standardized, so different variants have a lot in common... but they also have a lot of difference. Not all SQL databases adhere to the standard as closely as they should. Most have proprietary extensions to provide extra features. Among the major widely-used products, MySql and Access are probably the two that have strayed furthest from the standard, and in wildly different directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
select ID, count([Match ID]) as [TotalMatch ID] from 
(
SELECT  TblMatch.CustomerID1 as ID, TblMatch.[Match ID]
FROM TblMatch
UNION ALL
SELECT TblMatch.CustomerID2 as ID, TblMatch.[Match ID]
FROM TblMatch
) tmp
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  CUSTOMERID1,COUNT(*)
      FROM TBLMATCH
  GROUP BY CUSTOMERID1
 UNION ALL
    SELECT  CUSTOMERID2, COUNT(*)
      FROM TBLMATCH
  GROUP BY CUSTOMERID2
)ORDER BY CUSTOMERID1;
```

Comment: OP has tagged MySQL, MS SQL Server and MS Access, and you come with an Oracle answer...

Comment: I thought query logic is important !!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, your union all aggregated:

```
SELECT
  TblMatch.CustomerID1,
  Count(data.[Match ID]) AS [TotalMatch ID] 
FROM
  (
    TblMatch,
    (
      TblMatch.[Match ID]
    )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    TblMatch.CustomerID2,
    (
      TblMatch.[Match ID]
    )
  FROM
    TblMatch
  )
  data 
GROUP BY
  TblMatch.CustomerID1;
```