# How to add similar items in one using UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I am currently getting similar items in 2 places when joined using `UNION`.

What I want is that it should sum up and show a single item for similar items.

Here is my Query

```
select 
(Case 
When DHB = 'ABC.com' Then 'ABC Hospital'
When DHB = 'AOC.com' Then 'ABC Hospital'
When DHB = 'coe.com' Then 'EFG Hospital'
End) DHB
, count(*) NumberOfActiveUsers from (
select distinct Ltrim(Rtrim(substring(userid, charIndex('@', userId)+1, Len(userId)))) as DHB, userId from [RecordDB].[dbo].Event ae
where userId like '%@%'
) as Temp
where DHB in ('ABC.com','AOC.com','coe.com')
group by DHB

UNION

select distinct DHB,
 count(userid) NumberOfActiveUsers from (
SELECT DISTINCT userid,
CASE WHEN DHB in ('2.1','ABC001') THEN 'ABC Hospital'
     WHEN DHB in ('3.1','CDE001') THEN 'EFG Hospital'  
ELSE DHB END 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    userid, 
    CASE 
       WHEN CHARINDEX('-', e.name) > 0 
          THEN Ltrim(Rtrim(substring(e.name,0, charIndex('-', e.name)))) 
       ELSE e.name 
    END as DHB      
FROM
    [RecordDB].[dbo].Event ae
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].cUser cu ON cu.name = ae.userID
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].UAttribute ua ON ua.cUser = cu.uniqueId
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].[EIdentifier] ei ON ei.cUser = cu.uniqueId
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].[EIdentifierType] e ON e.uniqueId = ei.externalIdentifierType
WHERE
    (e.name LIKE '%ABC001%' OR e.name LIKE '2.1' or e.name LIKE '%CDE001%' OR e.name LIKE '3.1')   
) as aa
)as Temp2
group by DHB
```

OUTPUT

```
DHB            NumberOfActiveUsers
ABC Hospital           2
ABC Hospital           5
EFG Hospital           3
EFG Hospital           8
```

Expected OUTPUT should be

```
DHB            NumberOfActiveUsers
 ABC Hospital          7
 EFG Hospital          11
```

Comment: Add an outer query query which has a group by.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, can you please show me how to do this? Thanks

Comment: You've already done it in your second query (i.e. `FROM ( SELECT`), its a sub-query or derived table... just add another layer outside your full query. Have a crack... you'll get more satisfaction working it out.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, When I do this `select distinct * from(copied all the above query here)`, I am getting error `Incorrect syntax near ')'` at  the bottom of query. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You always need a derived table alias - like you have in your existing sub-query.

Comment: FYI: `DISTINCT` won't provide the required results, because you need a `SUM`. Therefore use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @DaleK, Thank you so much for your valuable guidance! I made it working now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Union with group by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624572/sql-union-with-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: @DaleK, I did `select  DHB, SUM(NumberOfActiveUsers ) NumberOfActiveUsers from(...)t group by DHB` .

Comment: Goup by your case statement in your first group by clause

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty solution:

```
select distinct * from (
  select * from part1
  union all
  select * from part2
) t;
```

(this is an alternative to the group by suggested in the comments, which is another valid, perhaps equivalent, avenue.)

**Edit 1**
As written in the comments, this "quick and dirty" way of doing things does not work since the OP requires the aggregate function `SUM`. Grouping by DHB, I believe this would work:

```
select DHB, SUM(NumberOfActiveUsers) as NumberOfActiveUsers
from (
      select /*your first statement*/ from part1
      union all
      select /*your second statement*/ from part2
) t;
```

Comment: OP requires a `SUM` therefore `DISTINCT` won't work.

Comment: You are correct, my bad. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Just add the group by solution as well.